# Why am i getting this number instead of the value, in this STACK program?

Tags: c, stack, undefined-behavior

In this implementation of stack program in C, when i print the value of pop(),why do i get that number? It should have printed '4' but instead i get an address like number. What might be the problem here?

```
#define MAX 5

typedef struct stack{
    int data[MAX];
    int top;
}stack;

int empty(stack *s){
    if(s->top==-1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int pop(stack *s){
    int x;
    x = s->data[s->top];
    s->top = s->top -1;
    return x;

}

void display(stack *s){

    while(!(empty(&s)) && (s->top)!=-1){
        printf("%d\n",s->data[s->top]);
        s->top=s->top-1;
    }

}


int main()
{
    stack s;
    init(&s);
    push(&s,2);
    push(&s,3);
    push(&s,4);
    display(&s);
    printf("Popped element is: ");
    printf("%d",pop(&s));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4
3
2
Popped element is: 4200976   
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.019 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: What does `init` and `push` do? Without a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is much harder to help you.

Comment: Your `display` function modifies the stack, which it shouldn't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude init() initializes the top to -1, and push adds the elements in the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the display function your top will always have the value of -1.
When using the pop function it will return the -1'th element in the array.
This is undefined behaviour and so the returned x can be anything.

Comment: @OmkarLubal: Then please consider accepting and upvoting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function `display` is invalid.

For starters this call

```
!(empty(&s))
```

has the argument type `stack **` while the parameter type is `stack *`. There should be

```
!(empty(s))
```

Though this check is redundant and may be removed.

And the function changes the data member `top` of the stack. As result the function `pop` called after the function `display` has undefined behavior.

The function can look like

```
void display(const stack *s)
{
    for ( int i = s->top; i != -1; i-- )
    {
        printf("%d\n",s->data[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 5

typedef struct stack
{
    int data[MAX];
    int top;
}   stack;

void init( stack *s )
{
    s->top = -1;
}

int empty( const stack *s )
{
    return s->top == -1;
}

void push( stack *s, int x )
{
    if ( s->top + 1 != MAX ) s->data[++s->top] = x;
}

int pop( stack *s )
{
    int x  = s->data[s->top--];
    return x;
}

void display(const stack *s)
{
    for ( int i = s->top; i != -1; i-- )
    {
        printf("%d\n",s->data[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    stack s = { { 0 }, -1 };

    init( &s );

    push (&s, 2 );
    push( &s, 3 );
    push( &s, 4 );
    display( &s );

    printf( "Popped element is: " );
    printf( "%d\n", pop( &s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

It yields the expected result

```
4
3
2
Popped element is: 4
```

Comment: That is not my question,i am having problem with pop() function.

Comment: No you don't, you have a problem with your display function.